# I use Mongodb in Centos(VirtualBox in my mac) and Spring4 in my mac.So they doesn't connect with each

Tags: spring, mongodb

I use Mongodb in Centos(VirtualBox in my mac) and Spring4 in my mac.So they doesn't connect with each.I tried researching application.properties and Maven source code and MongoDriver.I had already studied Spring MVC paternities in windows7.however I tries to use them in my mac and filed to build.

application.properties;

```
server.servlet.context-path=/dog
server.port=888
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

pom.xml;

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/mongodb-driver-3.10.2-javadoc.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application.java;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.example.demo.entity.ItemEntity;
import com.example.demo.repository.Repository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new ItemEntity("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new ItemEntity("Bob", "Smith"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (ItemEntity customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (ItemEntity itemEntity : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(itemEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

ItemEntity;

```
public class ItemEntity {
    @Id
    public String id;

public String firstName;
public String lastName;

public ItemEntity() {}

public ItemEntity(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
            id, firstName, lastName);

}
```

Repository;

```
public interface Repository extends MongoRepository<ItemEntity, String>{

public ItemEntity findByFirstName(String firstName);
public List<ItemEntity> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

error message;

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication error when accessing mongodb through Spring Boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086471/authentication-error-when-accessing-mongodb-through-spring-boot-app)