# Error authentication to MongoDB - Exception authenticating MongoCredential

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Just working locally on a Windows machine, with a Java Spring Boot 3.1.0 app and a latest mongo db version, and getting failure when connecting the app with database.

The db is deployed locally with the next docker command:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongo-db -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=adrian -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=documents mongo:latest
```

And the app has next connection properties to the database:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=documents
spring.data.mongodb.username=adrian
spring.data.mongodb.password=password
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

Or using uri:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://adrian:password@localhost:27017/documents?authSource=admin
```

When any operation is performed through the database, this next error is printed:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='adrian', source='documents', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
```

Also tried to create database manually after running the container, and then initializing the app, but the problem persists:

```
docker exec -it dd1b012c0e1a /bin/bash
use admin
db.auth('adrian', 'password')
use documents
```

Anyone knows, which is the source of the problem?

Comment: I have no clue about Docker, but I assume the user is created in database `documents` rather than `admin`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could be happening here is that you could be facing a configuration mix up.

1. Either use all the properties separately and let Spring set things up for you.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=documents
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=password
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

or

2. Just use the uri.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/documents?authSource=admin
```

Also for good measure, you might want to also intialize your DB when you run the Docker instance.

```
-e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=documents
```

Comment: Hey @Hermann Steidel, thanks for your reply. I just tried initializing db when running docker instance and with both cases, with uri and properties separately, but the error persists. Any idea what could be?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but, try changing the username from `root` to something else like `admin`. You'll have to do it on the container as well of course!

Comment: Tried but the problem persists. I tried to initialize database manually once the container is running (code in question edited), but nothing :(

Comment: Looks like there might a bug in 3.1.0? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35632

Try moving to Spring 3.1.1. Worth a shot.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is in the line of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086471/authentication-error-when-accessing-mongodb-through-spring-boot-app

Where someone commented they needed to add `?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1` to the URI. However, based on the Mongo Documentation `SCRAM-SHA-256` is the default value. So you might want to try both.  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/auth/#:~:text=SCRAM%2DSHA%2D256%20is%20the,algorithm%2C%20to%20authenticate%20your%20user.

Comment: Hey I finally found the problem, it was that the port 27107 was already used by another service, that happened when the machine turned on. So when I was trying to connect, it was trying to connect to another mongo instance with other credentials not same of properties file. Here is the issue: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-authentication-failed-with-spring-data-uri/109256/12

Comment: Interest, if that was the case, I would have suspected the `docker run` command to fail because the port was already in use. Glad you sorted it out though!